# Why is the isolatedModules option disabling typechecking in tests?

Tags: typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

I using a typescript testing setup with ts-jest. In project tsconfig the isolatedModules option is set to true. This disables typechecking of my test if i run them with jest. This is also documented for ts-jest: https://huafu.github.io/ts-jest/user/config/isolatedModules

Why is this happening? For the normal build process besides the test the isolatedModules option does not disable the typechecking. Addtionally the typescript docs does not mention something like disabling typechecking for this option: https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#isolatedModules
So I do not understand why its not working in the same way for the tests